# Can I rely on event execution order for base classes to avoid unnecessary virtual members?

Tags: c#, event-handling, derived-class

Sometimes I want my derived class to react on some base class event and change the state before any other subscribes can be notified.

Do I need to duplicate `protected virtual void HandleXBeforeOthers(...)` for each event or can I rely on event execution order like this?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public event X EventA;
    void RaiseA(...)
    {
        if (EventA != null) EventA(this, ...);
    }

    ...
}

public class Derived : BaseClass
{
    public Derived()
    {
        EventA += ...
    }
}
```

The "`protected virtual`" approach would be:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public event X EventA;
    void RaiseA(...)
    {
        HandleEventABeforeOthersCan(...);
        if (EventA != null) EventA(this, ...);
    }

    protected virtual void HandleEventABeforeOthersCan(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}

public class Derived : BaseClass
{
    protected override void HandleEventABeforeOthersCan(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what kind of guarantee you want.

Constructors are executed after field initializers, and base class constructors are executed before derived class constructors. So, just as your own `Derived` class is adding a subscriber to the event in its constructor, so too could have a base class done so before yours.

To make matters worse, while it's definitely frowned upon, there is nothing to stop a base class constructor from passing `this` out to some other code, where it would get a chance to subscribe to the event before your `Derived` class does.

Finally, only the class implementing the event has complete control over the actual order of execution of the event handlers. *Normally*, it would just invoke the delegate instance representing the event, which would execute each handler in the order in which it was subscribed. But there is nothing stopping the implementer of an event from maintaining and using the event subscriptions in some other way.

E.g. it could implement the event explicitly and do something like `eventField = value + eventField;` in the `add` method (reversing subscription at the time of subscription) or, when raising the event, explicitly enumerating the invocation list for the event's delegate object and invoking the handlers in reverse order.

Of course, all of those scenarios should be very rare, especially that last one (which would be *really* weird). Code that deviated from the normal event implementation is and should be very uncommon. But can you be *guaranteed* the code isn't like that? Not without a promise from the person who wrote the code (and even there, people are fallible and may forget or accidentally break their promise).

So if you want something close to an iron-clad guarantee that your code will execute before any other, you need to make your own class `sealed` (so no one else can override the event-raising method), and do your processing before calling the base class implementation of the method by overriding the virtual method that actually raises the event.

Even there, you are relying on an implicit promise that the event won't be raised via any other mechanism. But that's about as good a guarantee as you're going to get.

Comment: My question is more about the case when I control both base and derived classes. It looks like then I can subscribe to events in derived class constructor without any worries (cause I know that I'm not doing anything tricky with add/remove in base class). The client (who also subscribes to the same event) will receive the event only after it's processed by the derived class.

Comment: Yes, if you are careful about the implementations of the base class constructor (including not calling out to other code that would then see your `this` reference), you should be fine. Though I can't help but wonder what the specific reason is for not following the normal .NET idiom, of simply making the `RaiseA()` method virtual (in the idiom, this would normally be called `OnA()`) and having derived classes override if they wanted to intercept/preprocess/etc.

Comment: "making the RaiseA() method virtual" - I don't use RaiseA, instead I use my extension method Raise directly on event. Of course I can do that only when I'm sure it's not needed to raise base class events from derived.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see...that wasn't quite clear to me from the code examples given. Yes, if you don't already have a virtual method for raising a specific event, then I guess subscribing to the event in derived class constructors is a reasonable alternative, provided you're careful.